# Trace of Hermitian Positive Semidefinite Matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse, trace, positive-definite

Well, the question I want to ask is as follows.

Suppose A and B are Hermitian Positive Semidefinite (PSD) matrices, I wonder if it is possible to prove $Tr(A*(A+B)^{-1})\in (0,1]$ (if it is correct)?

If not, how about when A is of rank 1?

Thanks a lot!

---

Above is the original question.

In another version, I want to prove $Tr(a_i a_i^H (AA^H))=1$ provided $A$ is non-singular. ($a_i$ is the $i$th column of $A$. The upper script H means conjugate transpose.)

Any idea?

---

I modify the original question as: if A and B are hermitian PSD and (A+B) is nonsingular, how to prove the following?

$Tr(A*(A+B)^{-1})\le rank(A)$

Comment: Why should $A+B$ be non singular?

Comment: What does $*$ mean here? Is it the multiplication operation?

Comment: @user251257 Suppose it's full rank, actually it is something like $A+B+I$, where A and B are hermitian PSD.

Comment: @G_0_pi_i_e Yes.

Comment: @Mafen think about diagonal matrices. It is in general wrong.

Comment: @user251257 Yes, thanks. But for A being of rank 1, I think it's right.

Comment: $A = e_1e_1^T$ and $B = e_2e_2^T$ in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @user251257 I mean let's just assume A+B is non-singular, e.g. B=I.

Comment: @Mafen in my example $A+B$ is non singular and $A,B$ are hermitian, positive semidefinite, and rank $1$.

Comment: @user251257 Yeah, I see, thanks. I need to modify the range to be (0,1]. And would you take a look at the new version of problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a proof for the new version (actually simpler version of the original problem), as follows.

$Tr(a_i a_i^H (AA^H)^{-1})=a_i^H (AA^H)^{-1}a_i$

Since A is nonsingular and we have $A^{-1}a_i=e_i$, where $e_i$ is a column of all zeros except the $i$th element. The reason is that $A^{-1} A=I$, thus $A^{-1}a_i$ is the $i$th column of $I$, the identity matrix.

Thus $a_i^H (AA^H)^{-1}a_i=e_i^H e_i=1$.